# Знаки препинания перед "где", "чем", "как"

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите расставить знаки препинания, пожалуйста!

1. Вот где_ где, скажите мне, его найти?!
2. Умнее_ чем я, да?
3. Ад выглядит_ как наш город.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Вот где, где, скажите мне, его найти?! (Эмоциональный повтор слов).

2) Умнее, чем я, да? Запятая перед сравнением.

3) Ад выглядит как наш город. Сравнительный оборот является именной частью сказуемого.

Comment: Вера, а где связка при именном сказуемым?  Ад как наш дом - сомнений не вызывает.

Comment: Можно считать, что связка полузнаменательная по аналогии с "казаться", а эта связка точно входит в перечень полузнаменательных.

Answer (score 0):

Ад выглядит как наш город. Запятая не нужна. Что-то вроде уподобления, а не сравнения. Т.е. не получается разделить.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Думаю, что здесь высказана мысль о тесной связи оборота со сказуемым, что и определяет отсутствие запятой. Не огорчайтесь, Ivan, мне за мой первый ответ тоже поставили минус.

Comment: Вера, вот здесь я с вами согласен: здесь выражена тесная связь со сказуемым, т.е. поэтому не нужна запятая. Но это отнюдь не полузнаменательная или знаменательная связка.